# Do Lie Groups need to satisfy the “addition property”?

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra

In these lecture notes I don’t understand why the step with
$$g(\omega)=(1+...)(1+...)...(1+...)$$
is justified. It *would* be justified if we had the following property:
$$g(\omega_1)g(\omega_2) = g(\omega_1 + \omega_2).$$
Is this a necessary assumption for a Lie group? Or is it a provable assumption? Or is the step justified for some other reason?

[image]

Edit: After reflection, I believe that this is not a necessary assumption; however, this is equivalent to choosing the "affine parameterization" - which always *can* be done.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes, possibly; however, these lecture notes are from a physics course and I imagine more people here will be familiar with the subject. It can be moved if need be.

Comment: Just FYI, this somewhat hand-wavey and imprecise justification that any element close enough to the identity can be written as $\exp(X)$ for some element $X$ of the Lie algebra can be made perfectly rigorous (though it takes some more work). This is standard fare in any mathematical treatment of Lie groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from the first equation (MacLaurin series expansion) to the second (general expansion, upon division of parameter space into N equal parts) is done under the following **assumption:**

$g$ is an element of a connected neighbourhood of the origin/identity $e\in G$ (called the connected component of the identity).

As of such, it is always a member of a 1-parameter subgroup $h(\omega)$ by the following theorem:

> **Theorem 2.9.3** (*Cohn, P., "Lie Groups", CUP, 1965, p. 58*)
>
> Any connected 1-dimensional Lie group is analytically isomorphic either to the additive group of real numbers $\mathfrak{R}$, or to $\mathfrak{I}$, the additive group of real numbers *mod 1*. In particular, any 1-dimensional Lie group is locally isomorphic to $\mathfrak{R}$.

What does this theorem mean? That any $g\in G_0$ (the connected component of the identity) is expressible as a $h(\omega)$ with:

$$h(\omega_1)h(\omega_2) = h(\omega_1 + \omega_2) \tag{1}$$

Try to transform my $(1)$ into your second equation by considering the split of product.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any intuition for the proof of that theorem? Why must it be true?

Comment: Not so much, it is pretty dry. It comes basically from the Lie group being a manifold, hence locally connected, so paths can be taken as 1-dimensional Lie group themselves.